# How to train spacy trainned model

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

Is it possible to train spacy trained model such as model-best, model-last. If it is possible please tell me how to pretrain my model. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can train a spaCy model using [`spacy train`](https://spacy.io/api/cli#train), which is covered in the [official docs](https://spacy.io/usage/training) and the [course](https://course.spacy.io/en/). If you train a model it will produce `model-best` and `model-last` directories.